# Make can find specified target, Makefile cannot

Tags: makefile

Learning C the Hard Way, coding up my first makefile. The makefile is in the directory with the C files "ex1.c" and ex3.c".

```
make ex1
```

compiles an executable "ex1" correctly. The Makefile contains:

```
all:
     ex1
     ex3
```

but calling "make" returns error

```
make: ex1: No such file or directory.
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Why can `make` find the source code when specified as an arg but not when specified by the makefile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This snippet of makefile

```
all:
     ex1
     ex3
```

is telling make about one target `all` and that that target has *two* lines of recipe to run when the `all` target is requested.

So when you run `make all` (or `make` when `all` is the first/default target) make tries to run `ex1` and `ex3` as shell commands. Which clearly fails since they haven't been built yet.

Assuming you meant to tell make to build the `ex1` and `ex3` **targets** what you meant was

```
all: ex1 ex3
```

That all said for simple `ex1.c` -> `ex1` compilation you don't even need a makefile at all. Which is why the book doesn't bother telling you to create one yet.